# executing javascript after bringing xslt page by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xslt-2.0

how to execute javascript at a specific moment regardless of `setInterval()` or `onClick()`
the problem is that i'm getting an xslt page at a click (Ajax) and this page contains javascript that does not execute, although i wrote it in the script tags...

Answer (score 0):

If a page loaded with Ajax contains javascript, then indeed the code will not get executed. If you have control over the javascript and you get the javascript in a single variable you could 'eval' this code and execute the javascript that way. But it is not very secure.

You need to put the 'eval' after the ajax.get function. So in pseudo code:

```
var data = ajax.get("my.xslt");
var d = JSON.decode(data);
var xslt = d.xslt;
var script = d.script;

eval(script);
div.innerHTML = xslt;
```

Comment: well you're right thanks for the help, but where do i have to put the eval() function if the script won't execute ? p.s.: the script is accordion and it must be executed before the div.

Comment: You need to put the 'eval' after the ajax.get function. See my modified post.